# "Передают" ли дождь или снег?

Tags: семантика

Встречал, в частности нашёл в национальном корпусе, сочетание "передавать погоду". Можно ли, по аналогии с ним, построить выражения: "сегодня вечером передают дождь", "передают мороз", "передают низкую температуру и влажную погоду, с большим количеством осадков"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[передать](http://www.endic.ru/academic/Peredat-36651.html) (МАС)
4. Сообщить, распространить средствами технической связи. *Передать концерт по радио.*

> Экстренная телеграмма, **переданная** из Петербурга в ночь с девятого на десятое января безвестным телеграфистом в десятки городов, оповестила о страшных кровавых событиях в столице (Г. Марков. Строговы).

Думаю, что правильно фразы должны звучать так:
передавали прогноз погоды (= передавали погоду);
передают, что будет дождь (= передают дождь);
передали — будут сильные морозы (= передали сильные морозы).

То, что в скобках, можно считать *синоптическим сленгом* — все понимают, о чем говорится, и воспринимают эту информацию однозначно (зачем же "лишние" слова?).
Иногда по смыслу глагол имеет значение *обещать*.

*В одно мгновение мне стало не по себе. Неуютно и холодно. На завтра **передавали мороз*** (Т. Телегина. Записки облакам); *Делать это было, конечно же, лень, но дед Витя вспомнил, что к концу недели **передавали дожди*** (М. Рожков. Деревенская история).

[Передавали снег и метели](https://proza.ru/2014/01/15/1237) (В. Боровая)

Answer (score 1):

Можно, часто слышал такое. Вот про температуру не слышал, это ведь не погода.
"*Передают влажную погоду*" не очень звучит, диктор так не скажет. Лучше — "*передают большое количество осадков*".

Comment: А "передают дождь"?

Comment: Да, часто передают.

Comment: Так даже дикторы по радио говорят.